# Calculate vaccine efficacy confidence Interval using the exact method

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I'm trying to calculate confidence intervals for vaccine efficacy studies.

All the studies I am looking at claim that they use the Exact method and cite this free PDF: [Statistical Methods in Cancer Research Volume II: The Design and Analysis of Cohort Studies](https://publications.iarc.fr/Book-And-Report-Series/Iarc-Scientific-Publications/Statistical-Methods-In-Cancer-Research-Volume-II-The-Design-And-Analysis-Of-Cohort-Studies-1986) It is my understanding that the exact method is also sometimes called the Clopper Pearson method.

The data I have is: Person-years of vaccinated,  Person-years of unvaccinated,  Number of    cases among vaccinated,  Number of cases among unvaccinated,

Efficacy is easy to calculate: 1 - ( (Number of cases among vaccinated/Person-years of vaccinated) / (Number of cases among unvaccinated/Person-years of unvaccinated) ) * 100

But calculating the confidence interval is harder.

At first I thought that this [website](https://digitalcommons.usf.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1390&context=numeracy) gave the code I needed:

```r
testall <- binom.test(8, 8+162)
(theta <- testall$conf.int)
(VE <- (1-2*theta)/(1-theta))
```

In this example, 8 is the number of cases in the vaccinated group and 162 is the number of cases in the unvaccinated group. But I have had a few problems with this.

(1) there are some studies where the size of the two cohorts (vaccinated vs. not vaccinated) are different. I don't think that this code works for those cohorts.
(2) I want to be able to adjust the type of confidence interval. For example, one study used "one-sided α risk of 2·5%" where as another study used "a two-sided α level of 5%". I'm not clear if this effects the numbers.

Either way, when I tried to run the numbers, it didn't work.

Here is an example of a data sets I am trying to validate:

- Number of cases among vaccinated: 176
- Number of cases among unvaccinated: 221
- Person-years of vaccinated: 11,793
- Person-years of unvaccinated: 5,809

Efficacy: 60.8 95%

Two sided 95% CI: 52.0–68.0

Comment: Clopper-Pearson is not *the* exact method.  It is merely *an* exact method. Also, it calculates the CI for a proportion, not a difference in proportions or a vaccine efficacy, so *if* Clopper Pearson is an appropriate method for what you want to do (I'm not sure that it is), different sample sizes in the exposed and unexposed cohorts shouldn't matter.  For more details see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) or post on CrossValidated.